# How to delete first column from the file in Unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file like the one below -

```
|A|B|C|D  
|1|2|3|4
```

I want the result -

```
A|B|C|D  
1|2|3|4
```

I have tried using `cut` but I'm not getting the desired output. Please suggest how the first column can be removed?

Comment: `cut -c2- file` should work.

Comment: I used cut and it worked just fine.

Comment: Explain in what way cut is not producing the desired output.

Comment: Through grep `grep -oP '(?<=^\|).*' file`, `grep -oP '^\|\K.*' file`, through perl `perl -pe 's/^\|//' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`, delete the leading pipe symbol:

```
sed 's/^|//' file
```

There's an outside chance that on some versions of `sed` you'd need to escape the pipe.  You might be able to use the over-write mode too (though not all versions of `sed` support that):

```
sed -i .bak 's/^\|//' file
```